# how to get dropdown-menu item value and apend to text input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to change the value of a text box with the item I select from a dropdown menu. But it's not working.

```
<input class="dropdown-toggle" type="text" name="area-zone" id="area-zone" 
data-toggle="dropdown">

<div class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="area-zone">
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Jway</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Atrod</a>
</div>
```

This is my jquery code:

```
$('.dropdown-item').click(function (){
  $('#area-inout').val() = $('.dropdown-item').text();
})
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Please share the javascript that you've tried. What is not working about it?

Comment: please post  your `javascript` or `jquery` code

Comment: You are referencing `#area-inout`, but your input element is `#area-zone`.

Comment: Check this demo working Link : `https://jsfiddle.net/7oupwf3v/`

Comment: I checked. but not working!

Comment: Thanks. The problem was solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try :

```js
$('.dropdown-menu .dropdown-item').on('click', function(){
   
    $("#area-zone").val($(this).text())
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 

  
          <div class="dropdown">
           <input class="dropdown-toggle" type="text" name="area-zone" id="area-zone" 
            data-toggle="dropdown">
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                   <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Jway</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Atrod</a></li>

            </ul>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
$('.dropdown-menu .dropdown-item').on('click', function(){
   
    $("#area-zone").val($(this).text())
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="dropdown-toggle" type="text" name="area-zone" id="area-zone" 
data-toggle="dropdown">

<div class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="area-zone">
<a class="dropdown-item d-area-input" href="#">Jway</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Atrod</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Please check in `console` maybe you got the error? related to jquery or something else

Comment: But let me know what's the actual problem for my knowledge

Comment: I really don't know. The code didn't work, but it worked strangely now!

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

```js
$("div#dropDownSelect").click(function(e){
document.getElementById('inputBox').value = e.target.innerHTML;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="inputBox" value="" class="dropdown-toggle" type="text" name="area-zone" id="area-zone" 
data-toggle="dropdown">

<div id="dropDownSelect" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="area-zone">
  <a class="dropdown-item d-area-input" href="#">Jway</a>
  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Atrod</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Error in console : TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null

Comment: You are welcome. And on your js fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/4f9t2qm8/ . You are taking `aria-labelledby`  in the `document.getElementById`, where `document.getElementById` is for getting the data by id. I think...

Answer (score 0):

Please change the dorpdown_name with your selectbox name

```
<script>
    $('select[name="dorpdown_name"]').change(function() {
        $('#area-zone').val($(this).val());
    })
</script>
```